# Usage of var and scope attributes in <c:if> tags

Tags: jsp, jstl

The `<c:if>` tag is quite straight forward in use but I do not understand how to use the optional var and scope attributes. It is stated that these can be used to save the result of the condition's result, but how?

What if the code in between the tags is not declarative, or if it does not declare a value simply or directly e.g.

```
  <c:if test = "${true}" var="testVar" scope="request">
     <p>not a declarative result  <c:out value = "${salary}"/></p>
  </c:if>
```

I have tried searching for examples but could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read what you posted: "these can be used to save the result of the condition". So, whatever you have in the body of the tag is irrelevant. What is saved in the variable is the value of the condition (i.e. true or false, in this case, true).

This can be useful, for example in order to replace something like

```
<c:if test="${someComplexConditionToEvaluate}">
  bla bla
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!someComplexConditionToEvaluate}">
  bla bla
</c:if>
```

by

```
<c:if test="${someComplexConditionToEvaluate}" var="condition">
  bla bla
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!condition}">
  bla bla
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand now